# Vuejs nested lists pulled with AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, vue.js

I'm trying to recreate this vuejs nested list example from JSFiddle, but with the addition of AJAX: https://jsfiddle.net/928ao037/

I have my PHP

```
    $todos = array(
    'todos' => array(
        array(
            'text' => 'Learn JS',
            'subTodos' => array(
                array('text'=>'linting'),
                array('text'=>'bundling'),
                array('text'=>'testing'),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'text' => 'Learn Vue',
            'subTodos' => array(
                array('text'=>'Components'),
                array('text'=>'Virtual DOM'),
                array('text'=>'Templating'),
            )
        ),
        array(
            'text' => 'Build something awesome',
            'subTodos' => array(
                array('text'=>'Build'),
                array('text'=>'Something'),
                array('text'=>'Awesome'),
            )
        ),
    )
);

echo json_encode($todos);
```

and my JS/HTML:

```js
var apiURL = '../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_pull_facilities_and_apps';

Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '<li>{{subtodo.text}}</li>',
  props: ['subtodo']
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   todos: '',
  },
  methods: {
    start: function () {
   var self = this
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
   self.unloaded = true;
      xhr.open('GET', apiURL)
      xhr.onload = function () {
        self.todos = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      }
      xhr.send()
    }
  }
});

app.start();
```

```html
   <div id="app">
    <ul>
   <li v-for="todo in todos">
     {{ todo.text }}
     <ul>
    <todo-item v-for="subtodo in todo.subTodos" v-bind:subtodo="subtodo"></todo-item>
     </ul>
   </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

The parsed JSON is coming back in like this:
[todos output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNLMq.jpg)

I've tried passing the array from the jsfiddle directly into app.todos and it works, so I believe my component is set up correctly. When the AJAX pulls it in, it looks like everything is there, but the data type is: 'Object {**ob**: Observer}'. I'm not sure how to parse it or what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: I should add that the output of the above PHP is: {"todos":[{"text":"Learn JS","subTodos":[{"text":"linting"},{"text":"bundling"},{"text":"testing"}]},{"text":"Learn Vue","subTodos":[{"text":"Components"},{"text":"Virtual DOM"},{"text":"Templating"}]},{"text":"Build something awesome","subTodos":[{"text":"Build"},{"text":"Something"},{"text":"Awesome"}]}]}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just had to JSON parse the response.todos not just the response. I decided to use jquery for my json get function too, but I doubt that had anything to do with it.

```
            var app = new Vue({
              el: '#app',
              data: {
                  todos: '',
              },
              methods: {
                start: function () {
                  var self = this
                    jQuery.getJSON(apiURL, function(result){
                        self.todos = result.todos;
                    });
                }
              }
            });
```